Using switch_to_blog in pre_get_posts hook
I have a multisite WordPress with two sites in it (two languages), and I'm developing a theme for both of them.
I have a custom type (named 'lesson') that I want to have it shown in both of the sites.
So I ended up using pre_get_posts hook to reach my purpose, but the problem is when I change the blog id in this action, the other actions (and filters) don't work anymore!
I chose to have two sites for translation because generally the contents of the sites are different, but there is some of data that should be in both of the sites.
So, I decided to insert the 'lesson' data in only one of the sites and use the data in the second one.
So, I have (for example) this two urls:
example.com/en/lesson1
example.com/fr/lesson1

And I want to have the same data of both pages and the deference between them is the languages of the pages (except the post content that are the same).
So I used the 'pre_get_posts' hook to change the query before getting the data from db and make it fetch the data from the first site only:
function change_to_main_site_on_lesson( $query ){
    if( 'lesson' == $query->query['post_type'] && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_single() ){
        switch_to_blog( 1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_to_main_site_on_lesson' );

And, boom! this works! Both urls are working in expected language! very good! But... There is a problem.
The problem is that the code only changes the blog id to "1" and doesn't restore it to the current blog, and it has to be restored to the current block AFTER the query runs.
So I decided to use another action to do that, and that action is 'get_posts', because it runs after the query runs.
So I added this code to do that:
function return_to_currrent_site( $posts, $query ){
    restore_current_blog();
}
add_action( 'get_posts', 'return_to_current_site' );

After that I realized that this action (and the other actions and filters) dose not work at all!
I found out that using switch_to_block() in the action using filter pre_get_posts makes the problem!
Any suggestions?

Just to be clear, you have Site A and Site B in a multisite install. On Site A you have a CPT with corresponding content in the database. On Site B this CPT does not exist, and therefor you don't have corresponding content in the database. On Site B you'd like to pull Site A's content for this type. Does this explain your situation in general? If so, are you trying to create URLs on Site B that would support this, too? Something like https://site-b/product/xyz?

Thank you for your comment @Chris. As I'm using the same theme in both sites, the CPT is actually exists in both of sites. But in site B I won't insert any data. So the slag (lesson) exists in both sites, so I CAN check if the page request is a "lesson" or not. So my code in 'pre_get_posts' is working good. But the problem is I can't use any actions/filters after that aciton.

I completely understand your comments about what is and isn't working. I have built several large WP multisite systems, many of which interact with each other despite what Step 0 says in the handbook. My personal recommendation is to treat these as two different sites, and have Site B make an API call into Site A "somehow". I think Site B probably shouldn't even have the CPT registered, that's just adding to the confusion. Use a rewrite hook and template redirect to handle this. Let Site A prepare the data as much as it needs to, hand it over to Site B and let it do whatever it needs then.

Thank you again. I know that using an API is a possible and a good choice, but I thought that it's more complicated (Regardless of my current problem).

I'm using the term "API" loosely. The reason I asked my initial questions was to try to see what all you were trying to do. If it is just list things and show individual things, I would use switch_to_blog, call get_posts and store in an array, call restore_current_blog and then return the array for the listing, and then use some template logic to show them.

Alternative solutions: A) write a function that reads data from site A and stores it on site B and set up a cronjob that executes it on a given frequency (eg. hourly); or B) create a database table (might even be a good idea to have it on an entirely separate database) and have both site A and B read from that table.

To what @cabrerahector, syncing from A to B is also potentially a way to solve this, but I'd caution against it if you start to field out your CPT with ACF or similar. Doing that requires syncing additional things which can greatly add to complexity over time. Further, by doing this "Site B" suddenly becomes "aware" of the content, so technically admins can start doing things with it (edit, rename, delete), so then you usually want to add guards around that (unless you want to support it, I guess).

The code above has two mistakes:

The correct hook to run after getting posts is not get_posts, It is the_posts.

The hook the_posts is prepared to be used in a filter not an action.


Changing these two mistakes solved my problem:
function change_to_main_site_on_lesson( $query ){
    if( 'lesson' != $query->query['post_type'] || $query->is_admin ){
        return ;
    }

    switch_to_blog( 1 );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_to_main_site_on_lesson' );

function return_to_current_site( $posts, $query ){
    if( 'lesson' != $query->query['post_type'] || $query->is_admin ){
        return $posts;
    }
    restore_current_blog();

    return $posts;
}
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'return_to_current_site', 10 , 2 );

